# Soundcloud api: Geo Tag search not working

Tags: tags, soundcloud, geo

Geo search tags appear not to be working.  I have an app that has been running for months with no changes.  It broke recently and upon troubleshooting I found that geo tag search, both specific and with wild card, returns no results.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { SC.initialize({  client_id: 'my id here'}); 
    SC.get("/tracks", {limit: 200, tags: 'geo:lon=-118.*'}, SearchTracks);

    });
var SearchTracks=function Search (tracks){
    for (var key in tracks)  
        {console.log(tracks[key].title+"   "+tracks[key].tag_list);
        }      
};
```

The same happens when I use any other combo of geo:lat and geo:lon.  Can someone from Soundcloud comment?

Comment: Have you find any solution?