# Geo tag filter with API?

Tags: api, soundcloud

Similar question here: [Search by geo filter with soundcloud api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906773/search-by-geo-filter-with-soundcloud-api)

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=CLIENT_ID&tags=geo:

returns a list of tracks with the geo tag, but once you try to specify the location to filter it returns 0 results. For exmaple:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=CLIENT_ID&tags=geo:lat%3D52.0*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not well documented but took a bit, this is how you do it.

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=CLIENT_ID&geo:
```

Comment: For me, this returns audio clips, but none have geotags associated with them.

Comment: Yeah, i stopped using soundcloud geo since I feel its depreciated and they just never updated the documentation

Comment: It seems you're right. Do you use an alternate source of geocoded user-contributed audio?