# Soundcloud API - geo tag filtering on tracks returns 503 service unavailable

Tags: api, tags, geolocation, soundcloud, http-status-code-503

I cannot seem to search by geotags using Soundcloud's API. Here's what I'm trying:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&tags=geo:lat=41.8819,geo:lon=87.6278

I'm getting a 503 Service Unavailable for only geo tags -- other tags work fine. Any advice?

--
Unanswered related questions

March 8th
[Soundcloud api: Geo Tag search not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233098/soundcloud-api-geo-tag-search-not-working)

April 9th
[Search by geo filter with soundcloud api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906773/search-by-geo-filter-with-soundcloud-api)

Comment: Have you tired contacting soundcloud support?

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation isn't too great, but if you do it this way it works

[http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&geo:lat=41.8819geo:lon=87.6278](http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&tags=geo:lat=41.8819geo:lon=87.6278)

Comment: This returns an empty array for me.